# two command buttons on a worksheet to show the same userform

Tags: excel, vba, userform, show-hide

**My Problem:**
I have one userform. To open this userform, I use two command buttons. With one command button, I add the data and with second command button (actually not a button but by double clicking on the row from a range), I actually update the existing data of the selected row of the active cell.

**My requirement:**
With the second function, I would like to hide certain checkboxes and textboxes as well as show a new textbox which is not a part of the first command button.

I hope I was clear to state my problem. Thank you and look forward for your solutions.

First commad button code

> `Sub Button3_Click()  Data_Entry.Show  End Sub`

Second code from the worksheet function

'''''

```
> ''''' Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range,
> Cancel As Boolean)
> 
> If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("A2:N250")) Is Nothing Then
>         Cancel = True
>         Data_Entry.Show Modal
>        With Data_Entry
>        Dim strCellComment As String
>             Dim CurrentRow As Long
>             Dim ws As Worksheet
>             Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")                       
>             .ComboBox5.Text = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3)
>             .ComboBox6.Text = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 4)
>             .ComboBox7.Text = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 5)
>             .ComboBox4 = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 27)
>            '.TextBox3.Text = ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Comment ': ws.Cells(CurrentRow, 3).Comment.Text Text:=Chr(100) End With
> 
> Else    Cancel = False  End If
```

Lets say I would like to hide certain textbox when i use the double click function

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show us some code of what you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer to how to hide a textbox is to simply add in a line like this:

```
TextBox1.Visible = False
```

However, I think a better method for you would be to just create a separate userform for this task. You can copy your existing userform (code and all) by right-clicking on it and clicking export, changing the name so you don't get a conflict, and then right-clicking and importing it back. Then make your changes and you're done!

Comment: yes got it working by using your quick answer.. Thank you